# How to trust javascript opensource libraries found in the internet

Tags: javascript, security, malware

Actually , I need to use some of JS libraries or packages found in the internet. But for security reasons , I have doubts using them.

For example this JS simplebar  found in github . It's cool, saves a lots of time ,  but how can I trust it ? Is there any malware in it ?

[SimpleBar](https://github.com/Grsmto/simplebar)

Is there any website listing trusted libraries ?

Thanks for advice

Comment: Check code in case it is not too long or complex or there are scan servers like https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload but not sure if it works with JS too (and URL probably works for whole web).

Comment: It's not JavaScript, you can aim the same question towards *any* library for any language out there. Ultimately, it's a matter of judgement and accepting some risk.

Comment: There is no list, and a list would be useless anyway, since it would be out of date before it was published. And why would you trust the one that published the list?

Comment: @some There _is_ a list: see my answer. Of course, "who watches the watchmen" is the obvious question, but for most people it's not worth worrying about. (If you're in finance or military, this changes, obviously.)

Comment: @Amadan There is a list of known vulnerabilities. That is easier and much different from a list of safe code.

Comment: @some: Right, that's fair enough. Whenever I see "safe" I read "not demonstrated to have vulnerabilities". I don't even trust my own code to be "safe" safe.

Comment: Found an odd collection, where AV reacts, but virustotal not - probably would have to upload local file there (https://github.com/HynekPetrak/javascript-malware-collection/) When I test 3 files from general src folder, then V.T. did not found anything (0/56).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `npm` registry, `npm audit` scans your installed packages for known vulnerabilities. More details [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/auditing-package-dependencies-for-security-vulnerabilities).

Obviously, it does not detect *unknown* vulnerabilities, so if you are really paranoid, reading all the source yourself is the only way to be absolutely sure.

Frequent updates of `npm` and infrequent and controlled updates to your packages decrease the risk.